# WSO2 identity server PDP how disable cacheing

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want disable decision caching, so in /repository/conf/security/entitlement.properties I tried

1. PDP.DecisionCaching.Enable=false
2. PDP.DecisionCaching.Enable=true and
   PDP.DecisionCaching.CachingInterval=30

But, when enabling/disabling a resource for a user, I have to wait 10 minutes before the decision changes from permit/deny or I have to restart IS.

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Do you have to wait 10 mins even you have disabled Decision caching?

Comment: Unfortunatly, yes.
Even if PDP.DecisionCaching.Enable=false

Comment: Hi @Abimaran Kugathasan
I also tried in this way:
1. enable/disable a resource for a user
2. call "clearDecisionCache" operation of EntitlementAdminService
3. call "getDecision"

But the decision doesn't change.
Maybe, disabling Decision caching requires others settings?

Comment: How did you enable/disable the resource for a user? By changing the policy?

Comment: No, I don't change the policy.
I created a user role for each policy condition.
When I delete the role for an user, the policy remains unchanged and the decision changes but only if I wait 10 mins or I restart IS.

Comment: Have you disabled the attribute cache as well? Otherwise the policy decisions will be based on cached attribute values

Comment: Hi @Hos. I used both configurations:  
  
PDP.DecisionCaching.Enable=true  
PDP.DecisionCaching.CachingInterval=30  
PDP.AttributeCaching.Enable=true  
PDP.AttributeCaching.CachingInterval=30  
PDP.ResourceCaching.Enable=true  
PDP.ResourceCaching.CachingInterval=30  
  
and  
  
PDP.DecisionCaching.Enable=false  
PDP.DecisionCaching.CachingInterval=30  
PDP.AttributeCaching.Enable=false  
PDP.AttributeCaching.CachingInterval=30  
PDP.ResourceCaching.Enable=false  
PDP.ResourceCaching.CachingInterval=30